# How to route mirrored traffic?

Tags: routing, mirror

There is a telco device which can send sip and rtp traffic to only two servers due to its abilities. My goal is to send all the traffic generated by this device to another server located in different site. In order to do that i located a switch between the device and the network which two servers exists and the mirrored the switch port attached to telco device to another switch port attached to router. I would like to ask you that if it is possible to route that mirrored trafic on router? 
[image: topology]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Route*? NO.

*Encapsulate* and send as a stream somewhere else (aka RSPAN)? Yes. (or *maybe*)

Also, all you can do with that traffic is look at it. You *cannot* pretend to be part of the conversation.

Comment: With certain Cisco devices (off the top of my head, 65xx switches and ASR100x routers), you can use ERSPAN to encapsulate the traffic into a GRE tunnel and route it to another site. It is, as far as I know, Cisco-proprietary, and support is limited to just a few devices and code versions.

Comment: There are ways to "trick" other platforms into do something like that (GRE tunnel), but it's complicated method to do something that shouldn't be done.